# Is it possible to pass an instance "pointer" to another process through a memory mapped file?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, .net-4.0, shared-memory

I'm basically searching for a way to pass instances across programs/processes *without* serializing the instances, in .NET 4.0.

Yes, I'm missing my good ol' 100% unsafe pointers ;)

I thought the new integration of Memory-mapped files to .NET 4.0 would help me, having read somewhere that you could pass references/pointers "natively" using it.

However, when I try something like

```
var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"C:\temp\test.mp", FileMode.Create, "mmf",
                                          1024*1024*300, 
                                          MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
var ss = new SimpleStruct();
ss.items = _items; //Collection of Items objects
var FileMapView = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();
FileMapView.Write<SimpleStruct>(0, ref ss); //Exception
```

I get the following ArgumentException:

```
The specified Type must be a struct containing no references.
```

Is it possible to pass references around using MMF? If it isn't, is there any way *at all* to pass instances around programs/processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't possible in unmanaged code either, a pointer value has no meaning in another process.  Managed objects live on the garbage collected heap, that will never coincide with the address of a MMF view.  Even if it somehow did, the garbage collector would cause havoc.  Primary reasons why it took 4 versions of .NET for MMFs to become supported.

Serializing managed objects to the view is inevitable.

Comment: I can easily infer the meaning, ie, the type of the data, from the context. That basically means that I would know how to cast my "void" pointer back to it's true type. Both processes would of course share a common assembly defining some common types. I guess what I would've liked to see was the ability to *pin* managed instances, just like you can do with unmanaged types.

Comment: It can't work by design.  The memory layout of managed objects is undiscoverable.  The JIT compiler takes advantage of that by reordering fields of a struct, for example, to achieve proper alignment and minimum total size.  Casting an IntPtr requires Marshal.PtrToStructure().  The managed version of memcpy().